# MVC Controller Action Gets Called Multiple Times When Layout Is Specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a problem where a controller action is called at least twice. I have a view that has another view as its layout page, and the view is called multiple times. If I remove the specification for the layout then the action is consistently executed once. I looked through StackOverflow and other sites but couldn't find a problem which had the same characteristics as mine so I'm posting a new question.

```
_ViewStart.cshtml:
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ProfileLayout.cshtml";
}

Index.cshtml inside my Profile folder: @{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";    
}
Index

Controller Action:
public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        //ToDo: BusinessLogic
        //This method gets called twice
        //******************//
        return View();
    }
```

It seem's like a simple problem and I'm definitely missing something obvious. I've posted the sample project on this site: https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=F2DAB940147490B0&id=F2DAB940147490B0%21140

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks

Update: Here's the view:
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "TestMVCProject";
        Layout = null;
    }

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TestMVCProject</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/ActiveSite.css" />    
    <link href="../../Content/themes/TestMVCProject/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">  
  <div id="loginimagecontainer">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginActions", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "LoginActionsForm" }))
  {  
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()      
  <a href="#"><img src="/images/icons/message-icon.png" width="60" height="60" alt="Messages" title="Messages"/></a>
  <a href="/Account/LogOff"><img src="/images/icons/log-out-icon.png" width="60" height="60" alt="Log off" title="Log off"/></a>
  }    
  </div>

  <div class="logotext"><img alt="TestMVCProject Logo" src="#" width="350" height="150" id="TestMVCProjectLogo" /></div>
    </div>    
  <div class="content profile">  
    <div id="leftPane">
        <img src="#" alt="Placeholder" width="165" height="200" id="ProfilePhoto" title="Profile Photo" />
        <div id="Username"></div>
        <div id="NavLinks">
            <div class="ProfileNavigation" onclick="Navigate('/Profile/Update')"><span>Profile</span><img src="/images/icons/edit-icon.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Profile" /></div>
            <div class="ProfileNavigation"><span>Search</span><img src="/images/icons/search-icon.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Search" /></div>
            <div class="ProfileNavigation" onclick="Navigate('/Photo')"><span>Photos</span><img src="/images/icons/camera-icon.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Photos"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
      <div id="adcontainer">
        <h4>Ads go here</h4>
        <p>content goes here</p>    
        </div>

    <div id="centerPane">
    @RenderBody()
    </div>     

  </div>
  @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml")
    <div id="redirectiondialog" class="dialog">
    <br />
    Hey, wait up... we're redirecting you over to the login page
    <br />
    </div> 

    <script type="text/javascript">    
        function Navigate(url) {
            window.location = url;
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the footer page:

```
 <div class="footer">
    <div class="fltrt">Copyright 2012 TestMVCProject Inc&nbsp;</div>
    <p><a href="/Profile/Test">About</a> | <a href="#">Contact</a> | <a href="#">FAQ</a> | <a href="#">Advertise</a> | <a href="#">Support</a> | <a href="#">Feedback</a> | <a href="#">Login</a> | <a href="#">Register</a> | <a href="#">Privacy</a> | <a href="#">Terms</a></p>    
</div>
```

Update:
@Tieson T: Thanks, I changed this to be Html.Partial instead of RenderPage. However the problem still persists as the action method still gets called twice... (Editing description as I don't have privileges to add comments)

Comment: What does your layout view look like?

Comment: I just updated the description and added this information now

Comment: not an answer or comment directly related to the question. But I got a similar error-pattern. I worked with views and partialviews but mistakenly called View in stead of PartialView for the PartialView, hence the _layout.cshtml got called twice etc ... . If you're tweaking something into an existing codebase and not working with view day in, day out, with mvc, an annoying mistake very quickly made. For all those who land on htis page with an issue, an additional possibility ... .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out the problem. There was this line in the code:

```
<img alt="TestMVCProject Logo" src="#" width="350" height="150" id="TestMVCProjectLogo" />
```

The `src` was going back to the same page. Once I replace it with a `""` it works fine now.

Comment: Maybe mark this as the answer if you can as it's still showing up as an unanswered question.

Comment: wow, wow, wow. what a PIA that was. in my case someone had embedded dozens of these throughout the codebase; copy/paste no doubt. this would never have occurred to me. it's funny that because the browser only loads each resource once the issue was kind of masked; if it had been 10 calls it would have been way less subtle and more detectable. thanks for posting your findings!!

Answer (score 4):

I also faced same problem. The Action was rendering twice.
The only problem was with

```
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

Dont know for what reason src attribute of image was causing to perform rendering twice on page.

I just changed it to ""`

```
<img id="blah" src="" alt="your image" />
```

and it is working fine now.

Comment: `<iframe src="#" ></iframe>` may have this issue

Answer (score 2):

It also happens when we are giving a image path, but, image does not exist on that path.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `_Footer.cshtml` view is just plain old HTML, there is absolutely no reason to call `@RenderPage()` to insert it into your layout. Use `@Html.Partial()` instead:

```
@Html.Partial("_Footer")
```

I honestly don't know for sure why the layout is called twice, but I assume `@RenderPage()` (which I've never had a need for) renders an entire HTML page and injects the results. You'd have to check the page source in your browser to confirm.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

@Url.Content(...) is causing the model to get called twice for me. Maybe some others issue as well

Answer (score 0):

guy's if none of the above works like me, try disabling Conveyor extension.

that mas my nightmare.

enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

Add a new middleware to identify what happining on the middle to see..

```
 public class ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
 {
     private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

     public ExceptionHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
     {
         _next = next;
     }

     public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
     {
         try
         {
             await _next(httpContext);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Exception handled by middleware ...");

             BaseResponse response = new BaseResponse(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new MessageDTO(ex.Message));
             httpContext.Response.StatusCode = response.status_code;
             httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
             await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(response);
         }
     }
 }

 // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
 public static class ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareExtensions
 {
     public static IApplicationBuilder UseExceptionHandlerMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
     {
         return builder.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
     }
 }

 public class BaseResponse
 {
     public int status_code { get; set; }
     public object data { get; set; } = null;
     public string token { get; set; }
     public bool isStatus { get; set; }
     public bool isAdmin { get; set; }


     public BaseResponse(int statusCode, object data, string token, bool isStatus, bool isAdmin)
     {
         this.status_code = statusCode;
         this.data = data;
         this.token = token;
         this.isStatus = isStatus;
         this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
     }

     public BaseResponse(int statusCode, object data)
     {
         this.status_code = statusCode;
         this.data = data;
     }


     public BaseResponse()
     {
         // default constructor
     }
 }

 public class MessageDTO
 {
     public string message { get; set; }

     public MessageDTO(string message)
     {

         this.message = message;
     }
 }
```

Register it

```
app.UseExceptionHandlerMiddleware();
```

See what happining in my case; there is no favicon in new migrated project and also some ong and jpg files. locate them everything perfect after.

Heyy microsoft.. There must be a clue..